# How to enter a date variable for an SQL string in a split database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need some assistance. I have my test database (unsplit) that runs this script perfectly.
But when I try and run it in the split database on our network, I keep getting an error message "Invalid use of NULL".

The data and tables in the two databases are exactly the same.
I have checked to make sure there are no null fields in the tables on the split database and there are none.
I used the same computer to run this sub on both databases.
Also checked the actual query on the split set and the information is there.

I think it is to do with the date variable, but am not sure. The whole module has a few subs that run fine on the split database until it reaches this sub. This sub is the only one that looks at dates, which is why I am thinking it is an issue with the date variable.

What is the next thing I can try to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

```
Public Sub getSalesQtysLast4Months(dateForReport As Date, SupplierID As Long, planCurrencyID As Long, planROE As Single, countryID As Long)

Dim rptStartDate As Date
Dim rptEndDate As Date

rptStartDate = dateForReport - 120
rptEndDate = dateForReport

' here we need to get from the sales inv lines
strSQL = "SELECT tblInvLines.intStockCode_ID, Sum(tblInvLines.intQuantity) AS SumOfintQuantity " _
        & " FROM tblStockItemsBasic INNER JOIN (tblInvoicesHeaders INNER JOIN tblInvLines ON tblInvoicesHeaders.ID_InvHeaders = tblInvLines.intInvHeaders_ID) ON tblStockItemsBasic.ID_StockCodes = tblInvLines.intStockCode_ID " _
        & "WHERE dtmInvoiceDate Between #" & rptStartDate & "# And #" & rptEndDate & "# " _
        & "GROUP BY tblInvLines.intStockCode_ID, tblStockItemsBasic.intSupplierID " _
        & "HAVING clng(intSupplierID)='" & SupplierID & "';"
        
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsDAO = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right about the date variable. I have the best luck when I format the date as a string. For example

```
& "WHERE dtmInvoiceDate Between #" & Format$(rptStartDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & Format$(rptEndDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# " _
```

Not sure about non-US formats.

Answer (score 0):

"/" is the date separator, so escape this and handle SupplierID as a number:

```vb
Dim rptStartDate As String
Dim rptEndDate As String

rptStartDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -120, dateForReport), "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
rptEndDate = Format(dateForReport, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")

strSQL = "SELECT tblInvLines.intStockCode_ID, Sum(tblInvLines.intQuantity) AS SumOfintQuantity " _
        & "FROM tblStockItemsBasic INNER JOIN (tblInvoicesHeaders INNER JOIN tblInvLines ON tblInvoicesHeaders.ID_InvHeaders = tblInvLines.intInvHeaders_ID) ON tblStockItemsBasic.ID_StockCodes = tblInvLines.intStockCode_ID " _
        & "WHERE dtmInvoiceDate Between #" & rptStartDate & "# And #" & rptEndDate & "# " _
        & "GROUP BY tblInvLines.intStockCode_ID, tblStockItemsBasic.intSupplierID " _
        & "HAVING intSupplierID = " & SupplierID & ";"
```